# Ubuntu wont recognize USB port

Tags: usb, kernel

I have a problem trying to run Ubuntu 11... Oneiric Ocelot, it starts to run, and it seems to work but we need the usb port to connect the keyboard and mouse, the problem here is that it doesn't recognize the usb ports, it wont show if something was connected or not.

It wont even turn the laser of the mouse on, nor the little led that turns on when it is connected. I'm using the i.MX53.

I found a lot of info of the trouble about usb ports but I need to enter some commands in terminal, but I can't since I can't even connect anything.

Comment: So the USB port is not even providing power, right?

Comment: nope, nothing, it doesn't power up anything, and since it is an embedded system I can't quite access the BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your computer and go to BIOS. If keyboard still doesn't work (you can't navigate BIOS menus with arrow keys), then the problem lies somewhere else than Ubuntu alone. Could be because of settings in the aforementioned BIOS or hardware malfunction.